# Fuel SDK (PHP) - Retrieve Subscribers from existing List (Filtered by CreatedDate) and AddSubscribersToLists

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, list, fuel-sdk

Ultimately, I want to Retrieve a group of Subscribers from the Main Subscriber List and Copy them to another already existing list.  The group will consist of a date range selection associated with the Subscriber's `CreatedDate`.

I am able to successfully Filter and Retrieve the Subscribers from the Main Subscriber List, but am struggling to add/copy the retrieved Subscribers to a separate and unique List. Is it possible to use the `AddSubscribersToLists` Method to achieve this?  Do I need to instantiate a new Client and/or Subscriber object?

Comment: Hope your sample data is fake.

Answer (score 0):

Using this post:  [Updating Subscribed does not change status](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43850/updating-subscribed-does-not-change-status)

I was able to resolve the issue using the AddSubscriberToList() function.

Comment: This post, as well:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82447/php-fuel-sdk-updating-subscriber-status-on-publication-list?rq=1